# cPanel ssh ftp application to transfer files to another server

Tags: cpanel, ftp, transfer, files

I have to transfer ~6GB of data from my server to another which I don't own.

On my server I have ssh access, and I have SFTP console client. The thing is, other server only supports plain old FTP and I can't connect to it using SFTP (at least I don't know how to do it, maybe it's possible).

So does SFTP also support plain FTP connection or is there another utility on cPanel server I could use?

I have tried to use php script to copy file by url but target server ran out of memory (only damn 64MB)

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use FTP? You can shell in and open an FTP session from the command line. It is a bit more painful, but since you have only one file, it should be easy enough.

Comment: there is no FTP command for some reason

Comment: it gives me -bash: ftp: command not found

Comment: Most FTP servers will install a client. If you have an FTP server installed, check to see what the shell client would be. If you have an FTP server installed, perhaps you can download your file to your desktop and then upload it to the other server using your favorite GUI FTP. Otherwise, maybe someone can point to some shell clients since I have no clue on which ones work best where. If you have a web server, perhaps you can create a symlink from the rootdir to the file and do an HTTP download, then upload using your favorite GUI FTP.

Comment: Thing is, I want to avoid downloading 6GB and than uploading it again, since I have 0.5 Mb/s upload and I need to do this by tomorrow.

Comment: Gotcha! See if pftp is installed. You can do man pftp, or just pftp at the shell command line.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I have succeeded by making this little php script:

```
<?php
exec('wget http://sourcesite.com/backup.zip');
```

I mean, it's still transferring, so I'm not sure if there's some size limit but we'll see.

Comment: I forgot about wget! Good news!! It should work just fine.